# Hotelling's T for Matrix Normal Distribution

Tags: multivariate-analysis, multivariate-normal-distribution, hotelling-t2

Suppose you observe matrix normal $\mathbf{X}_i \sim \mathcal{MN}_{m,p}\left(\mathbf{M},\mathbf{U},\mathbf{V}\right)$, for $i=1,2,\ldots,n$. That is $\mathbf{X}_i$ is an $m\times p$ matrix which is multivariate normal when you 'vec' it: $\operatorname{vec}\left(\mathbf{X}\right) \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\operatorname{vec}\left(\mathbf{M}\right),\mathbf{V}\otimes\mathbf{U} \right)$.

Is there a version of Hotelling's $T^2$ test for testing the hypothesis that $\mathbf{M} = \mathbf{0}$? It would seem that 'vec'ing out the $\mathbf{X}_i$ and then applying the usual Hotelling's test would allow too many degrees of freedom in the covariance estimate. However, there does not seem to be a straightforward way to estimate $\mathbf{U}$ and $\mathbf{V}$ in the matrix-normal setting (Dutilleul's MLE method aside), especially one that would result in a Wishart estimate of $\mathbf{V}\otimes\mathbf{U}$.

Comment: Viroli's work on ['matrix-variate regression analysis'](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0047259X12000966) comes close, but imposes some assumptions which I don't think will apply here.

Comment: Can we do this by computing the ratio of likelihoods? I think we can derive the Hotelling's T by the likelihood ratio.

Comment: @inmybrain that's a good point. Dutilleul's method gives the MLE, so it could be used in the constrained and unconstrained cases. This would result in an approximately $\chi^2$ test, as opposed to the $F$ test in Hotelling's test. I should have also revealed that I am interested in the distribution of the statistic in the non-null case so that I can construct confidence intervals. I don't know enough about Wilk's Theorem to know if that falls out automatically.